# UNMET DEPENDENCIES in parrot 3.6?

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel

i tried some solutions from the web to solve but of no vain.
please help how i can solve the issue.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for harry: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jsql : Depends: jsql-injection but it is not installed
 linux-headers-amd64 : Depends: linux-headers-4.9.0-parrot25-amd64 but it is not installed
 linux-image-amd64 : Depends: linux-image-4.9.0-parrot25-amd64 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`$cat /etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 3.5 _Parrot_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170307-05:27]/ parrot contrib main non-free

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 3.5 _Parrot_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LIVE/INSTALL Binary 20170307-05:27]/ parrot contrib main non-free
┌─[harry@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $uname -a
Linux parrot 4.9.0-parrot18-amd64 #1 SMP Parrot 4.9.18-1parrot18 (2017-04-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list` :

```
# parrot repository
# this file was automatically generated by parrot-mirror-selector
deb http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free 
# deb-src http://mirrordirector.archive.parrotsec.org/parrot/ parrot main contrib non-free
```

Comment: Welcome to SU , please [edit here](https://superuser.com/posts/1210014/edit) by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `uname -a` . It is better to add the output command by copy and past rather than adding an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages that had unmet dependencies were broken. Hence i had to remove them from my operating system. I used synaptic package manager to do that. This resolved the issue of unmet dependencies.

If you are unable to upgrade the parrot operating system this is because one of the mirrors site is down. You can change mirror site in `sources.list` or `parrot.list` . `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list`.

[parrot os mirrors-list](https://docs.parrotsec.org/doku.php/mirrors-list#mirrors-list)